# Changing the text when toggle

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the text when the user clicks but does not seems to work ..below is the code.

not working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3jt3P/1/

```
<a href="#" class="slide" onclick="firstclick();">Show First</a> ... 
<a href="#" class="slide1" onclick="secondclick();">Show Second</a>

<div id="one" class="content">one</div>
<div id="second" class="content">two</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function firstclick() { 
            $('#second').hide();
            $('#one').slideToggle(400, function () {
                debugger
                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                    $('.slide > a').text('Hide First');
                    $('.slide1 > a').text('Second');
                }
                else {
                    $('.slide > a').text('First');
                } 
            });
            return false;

        } 
        function secondclick() { 
            $('#one').hide();
            $('#second').slideToggle(400, function () {

                if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
                    $('slide1 > a').text('Hide Second');
                    $('slide > a').text('First');
                }
                else
                    $('slide1 > a').text('First');

            });
            return false;
        } 

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Hide the "view" div.
            $('#one').hide();
            $('#second').hide();

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your jQuery refers to id's and classes that just dont exist in your markup! This is a sloppy question, without a good description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i missed when i copy and past, i will update the code

Comment: While you're at it you should provide a good, simple working example of the problem using http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: dude working example? then why would i ask if the working example is working :)

Comment: By working, I mean something that you can interact with. Something that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: okay i have added the link - not working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3jt3P/1/

Comment: These selectors that you are using in your script: `'.slide > a'` imply a child anchor element within another element that has the class of "slide" but that is not what's in your html code. Your html has an anchor element that is classed as "slide" which would need this selector to target: `a.slide`

Comment: No, that doesnt work, you've forgotton to set it to jQuery for starters. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eWExr/

Comment: Jamiec: but does not change the title, so if i click on "Show First" the label should changed to "Hide First" vice versa

Comment: I know, it was a non-working example, a starting point for others to see the problem you were having.... that was the point!! Anyway see my answer for a *working* example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this slightly differently; markup your links with `data-*` attributes and use just one event handler to control them showing/hiding of the associated content.

Make your markup something like:

```
<a href="#" class="slide" data-content="#one" data-text="first">Show first</a>
<a href="#" class="slide" data-content="#second" data-text="second">Show second</a>

<div id="one" class="content">one</div>
<div id="second" class="content">two</div>
```

Notice ive added 2 attributes:

- `data-content` contains the id of the associated content
- `data-text` contains the suffix used in the link.

Ive also changed both links to have the same class - this could be anything but allows me to target the links so I can attach the same behaviour:

```
$('.slide').on("click",function(){
    var $link = $(this);
   var contentid = $link.data('content');
    $('.slide').not($link)
               .filter(function(){ return $(this).data('contentvisible');})
               .trigger('click');
    $(contentid).slideToggle(400,function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible')){
            $link.data('contentvisible',true).text('Hide ' + $link.data('text'));
        }
        else{
           $link.data('contentvisible',false).text('Show ' + $link.data('text'));                
        }
    });
});
$('#one').hide();
$('#second').hide();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/htn3S/1/

**Edit**: Ive update the above to include the functionality of hiding other visible elements before showing one.

Comment: there is slight issue, if i click on both first and second link it shows both divs and if i click on first link and the label says hide first and if i click on second link the label says hide second, so at a time one label should be displaying show and one lable should be displaying hide...the naming is not toggle properly

Answer (score 0):

there is no such element as `.slide > a` in your markup

try this (btw this is a update from Jamiec's jsfiddle fix)
http://jsfiddle.net/eWExr/6/